# How to construct query using like operator for multiple conditions from a python list in spark sql?

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have spark sql query which requires using like operator. for example:

```
spark.sql("select * from tbl where name like  '%apple%' ")
```

Now I have a long list of values

```
name_list = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', .......]
```

My question is how I can build my query from the long python list. What I need is a query like below:

```
spark.sql("select * from tbl where name like '%apple%' or name like '%orange%' or .... ")
```

The python list is long and can change. I certainly do not want to hard code everything. Wondering if there is any concise way to achieve that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the or condition using the list of names like this:

```
import functools

condition = functools.reduce(
    lambda acc, x: f"{acc} or name like '%{x}%'",
    name_list[1:],
    f"name like '%{name_list[0]}%'"
)

spark.sql(f"select * from tbl where {condition}")
```